# Which statistics test should I use to check difference in frequency between 2 populations?

Tags: python, statistics, chi-squared, t-test, population

I have two population and I want to known if their difference is significant or no (since the population B is the result of a subset of population A after some filtering criteria).
Which test should I use (since I have only 2 numbers). I am confused trying to find the correct approach (and implement it in Python).
Thanks a lot

[image]

Comment: Do you really mean populations, or samples? Just making sure that we are not mixing the two concepts.

Comment: sorry you are right. It is a sample (all the data that I can have but not all the data available 'in nature')